# ArityException with arity of (-1)

Tags: debugging, macros, clojure

There is a macro and I've been trying to figure this error out `ArityException Wrong number of args (-1) passed to: user/bar  clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1 (Compiler.java:6557)`. I tried to debug the but I'm not understanding why there's an arity of (-1) when I try to expand the macro.

I'm running the following code.

```
(defn foo [x] (println x))

(defmacro bar [exp]
  (let [length (count exp)]
    (cond
      (= length 0) '()
      (= length 1) exp
      :else (let [[head & tail] (vec exp)
                  [new-tail] (bar tail)]
        `(trap (~head ~@new-tail))))))

(macroexpand '(bar (inc 1)))
```

Anyone have any idea as to what's going on with the arity of (-1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `*e` var from the REPL I printed the stack-trace.

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (-1) passed to: user/bar
                                Compiler.java:6557 clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1
                                     core.clj:3703 clojure.core/macroexpand-1
                                     core.clj:3712 clojure.core/macroexpand
```

This points to the `clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1` method in [`Compiler.java`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6611), where I found this line:

```
throw new ArityException(e.actual - 2, e.name);
```

If `e.actual` is `1` the result is `-1` for the first argument to the `ArityException` constructor. There's a JIRA ticket [here](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1279) mentioning this very confusing `ArityException` message.

Based on what this ticket is saying I started to look for an `ArityException` somewhere else and found it in the use of `count` and `vec` as if `exp` was always a list.

The problem is that when calling the macro `bar` recursively the argument is actually the **symbol** `tail` which is not a collection and this call is actually macro-expanded when the macro itself is created **not** when it is called.

Changing the code for the macro so that it accounts for possible values that are not lists fixes the problem, although I think the resulting macro doesn't do what you were looking for.

```
(defmacro bar' [exp]
  (prn exp)
  (let [length (if (seq? exp) (count exp) 0)]
    (cond
      (= length 0) '()
      (= length 1) exp
      :else 
      (let [[head & tail] (if (seq? exp) (vec exp) [exp])
            [new-tail] (bar' tail)]
        `(trap (~head ~@new-tail))))))
;; tail

(macroexpand '(bar' (inc 1)))
;; (inc 1)
;;= (user/trap (inc))
```

Comment: I totally forgot about checking `*e`, I'm new to Clojure. But thanks for the link and mentioning the `*e` var, your post has helped!

Comment: @Petesta I found the problem. Please check the answer above.

Comment: Thank you for finding that out and the explanation! It was very helpful.